# Python Flask downloading a file returns 0 bytes

Tags: python, flask, download, content-disposition

Here is the code my flask server is running:

```
from flask import Flask, make_response
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
        return str(os.listdir("."))

@app.route("/<file_name>")
def getFile(file_name):
        response = make_response()
        response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = ""\
        "attachment; filename=%s" % file_name
        return response    

if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.debug = True
        app.run("0.0.0.0", port = 6969)
```

If the user goes to the site, it prints the files in the directory. However if you go to site:6969/filename it should download the file. However I am doing something wrong as the file size always 0 bytes and the downloaded file has no data in it. Any thoughts. I tried adding the content-length header and that didn't work. Don't know what else it could be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All that header does is tell the browser to treat the response data as a downloadable file with a certain name.  It doesn't actually set any response data which is why it's blank.

You'd need to set the file contents on the response for it to work.

```
@app.route("/<file_name>")
def getFile(file_name):
    headers = {"Content-Disposition": "attachment; filename=%s" % file_name}
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        body = f.read()
    return make_response((body, headers))
```

EDIT - Cleaned up code a little based on [api docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.make_response)

Comment: That makes sense. Then just a follow up question. There would be no difference then between your code above doing something like this instead right?:

with open(file_name, 'r') as f:

    response = make_response(f.read())

response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = ""\

"attachment; filename=%s" % file_name

return response.

Thanks Danny!

Comment: Yeah that should work, you can also pass headers directly to `make_response` (I edited the answer, should work with Flask 0.9+).

Comment: Last question Danny. Where did you find that you response object has a content method. Before your edit you had "response.content("Content goes here.")" I looked here http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.response_class but could not find any documentation on it.

Comment: Never mind I was trying your old solution with response.content = "foo" and that was not working so I assume it is deprecated. Your new solution shown in your example and in the api docs works. Thanks!

Comment: Better still, use [`send_from_directory()`](https://flask.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/#flask.send_from_directory).

Answer (score 10):

As danny wrote, you don't provide any content in your response, that's why you get 0 bytes. There is however an easy function [send_file](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.send_file) in Flask to return file content:

```
from flask import send_file

@app.route("/<file_name>")
def getFile(file_name):
    return send_file(file_name, as_attachment=True)
```

Note that the `file_name` is relative to application root path (`app.root_path`) in this case.

Comment: Yep sounds good. Or as Martijn Pieters mentioned in the above comment thread, [send_from_directory()](https://flask.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/#flask.send_from_directory) works as well. Thanks!