# Generating word docs with Flask?

Tags: python, flask, python-docx

I'm trying to spin up a single page flask application that allows users to download a word document. I've already figured out how to make/save the document using python-docx, but now I need to make the document available in the response. Any ideas?

Here's what I have so far:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from docx import Document
from cStringIO import StringIO

@app.route('/')
def index():
    document = Document()
    document.add_heading("Sample Press Release", 0)
    f = StringIO()
    document.save(f)
    length = f.tell()
    f.seek(0)
    return render_template('index.html')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

instead of `render_template('index.html')` you can just:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, send_file
from docx import Document
from cStringIO import StringIO

@app.route('/')
def index():
    document = Document()
    document.add_heading("Sample Press Release", 0)
    f = StringIO()
    document.save(f)
    length = f.tell()
    f.seek(0)
    return send_file(f, as_attachment=True, attachment_filename='report.doc')
```

Comment: This is the simplest way to do it so I marked this one as the answer.

Comment: Thanks it helped me a lot!

Answer (score 3):

**For those who pass after me...**

referring to these two links:

- [python 3.x ImportError: No module named 'cStringIO'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28200366/python-3-x-importerror-no-module-named-cstringio) [StackOverFlow Question]
- [TypeError: string argument expected, got 'bytes'](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/552) [GitHub issue]

> `io.StringIO` now replaces `cStringIO.StringIO`
>
> also it will raise an error
> as `document.save(f)` should receive a pass or binary file

**code should be like this:**

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, send_file
from docx import Document
from io import BytesIO

@app.route('/')
def index():
    document = Document()
    f = BytesIO()
    # do staff with document
    document.save(f)
    f.seek(0)

    return send_file(
        f,
        as_attachment=True,
        # Use attachment_name for Flask version < 2.2.0
        download_name='report.docx'
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `send_from_directory` as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24578372/3586654) answer.

If you are sending text, you could also use the `make_response` helper as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23354496/3586654) answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
return Response(generate(), mimetype='text/docx')
```

Generate() should be replaced with f in your case
For more information look at streaming in flask 
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/streaming/