# python 3.x ImportError: No module named 'cStringIO'

Tags: python-3.x, stringio, cstringio

How do I solve an `ImportError: No module named 'cStringIO'` under Python 3.x?

Comment: thx- accepting @SimonVissers solution. I should not have tried to install "email" it since it is available as a module. so just import email into code and make the changes to application code as needed.

Comment: This is a general issue when migrating to 3.x, and not just about installing any particular package e.g. email.

Answer (score 185, accepted):

From Python 3.0 changelog:

> The StringIO and cStringIO modules are gone. Instead, import the io module and use io.StringIO or io.BytesIO for text and data respectively.

From the [Python 3 email documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html) it can be seen that `io.StringIO` should be used instead:

```
from io import StringIO
from email.generator import Generator

fp = StringIO()
g = Generator(fp, mangle_from_=True, maxheaderlen=60)
g.flatten(msg)
text = fp.getvalue()
```

Comment: io module exists in my python environment. but I am unable to install email itself which was my problem. i.e. "pip install email" fails. Am I supposed to hack into some code and make changes for it to install ?

Comment: @jvi: You should not install `email`, you should only `import email` as it's part of the Python standard library.

Answer (score 16):

I had the same issue because my file was called **email.py**. I renamed the file and the issue disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I had the issue because my directory was called `email`. I renamed the directory to `emails` and the issue was gone.