# Python version related error

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to generate an HTML test report by using Selenium webdriver  library HTMLTestRunner. I am using Python 3.4 version and I have a version related error. Refer following snippet.

```
import unittest`enter code here`
import HTMLTestRunner
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.alert import Alert
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

class GreenlamTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUp(cls):
        cls.driver=webdriver.Firefox()
        cls.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        cls.driver.maximize_window()
        cls.driver.get('https://www.google.co.in')

    def test_checkTitle(self):
        assert "Google" in self.driver.title

    def test_searchtest(self):
        driver = self.driver
        elem = self.driver.find_element_by_name("q")
        elem.send_keys("pycon")
        elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

    @classmethod   
    def tearDown(cls):
    cls.driver.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    HTMLTestRunner.main
```

Output

```
Finding files... done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vaibhav\Desktop\Selenium Softwares\eclipse-jee-luna-SR2-win32-x86_64\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_4.0.0.201504132356\pysrc\pydev_runfiles.py", line 468, in __get_module_from_str
    mod = __import__(modname)
  File "C:\Users\vaibhav\Desktop\Selenium Softwares\Practice\pythondemo\Htmlreport.py", line 2, in <module>
    import HTMLTestRunner
  File "C:\Users\vaibhav\Desktop\Selenium Softwares\Practice\pythondemo\HTMLTestRunner.py", line 94, in <module>
    import StringIO
ImportError: No module named 'StringIO'
ERROR: Module: Htmlreport could not be imported (file: C:\Users\vaibhav\Desktop\Selenium Softwares\Practice\pythondemo\Htmlreport.py).
Importing test modules ... done.

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [python 3.4.0 email package install: ImportError: No module named 'cStringIO'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28200366/python-3-4-0-email-package-install-importerror-no-module-named-cstringio)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error because your folder name `Selenium Softwares` has a space in it where your Htmlreport is present. Replace the folder name to exclude space out of it, probably an underscore or camelCase, etc... like this `Selenium_Softwares` . Here's how -

```
file: C:\Users\vaibhav\Desktop\Selenium_Softwares\Practice\pythondemo\Htmlreport.py)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have tried above solution but still gets same error

Comment: Are those files and modules present in the path you specified?

Comment: @Girish: yes, all files and modules kept in same path

Comment: @MahsumAkbas do u mean HTMLTestRunner?.

Comment: i am using selenium, python 3.5 and  eclipse

Comment: How to resolve this issues                                                                 usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help