# Workaround for Google Earth Engine Python API and no support for `ee.mapclient` in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, gis, google-earth-engine

So I was using Google Earth Engine and working through some of the example code in their repo. I am using Python 3.6. Looks like Google will not support the mapping functionality in Python 3 through their `ee.mapclient()` anymore. I was wondering if anyone has found a suitable workaround? Let me outline the problem.

I tried to load the `ee.mapclient` to plot a map.

```
import ee
import ee.mapclient
ee.Initialize()
```

But I got an error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-6d4860410653> in <module>()
      1 import ee
----> 2 import ee.mapclient
      3 ee.Initialize()

/media/krishnab/lakshmi/anaconda3/envs/pMining/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ee/mapclient.py in <module>()
     29 
     30 import collections
---> 31 import cStringIO
     32 import functools
     33 import math

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cStringIO'
```

The `cStringIO` problem is easy enough to resolve as per:
[python 3.4.0 email package install: ImportError: No module named 'cStringIO'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28200366/python-3-4-0-email-package-install-importerror-no-module-named-cstringio)

So I went to post an issue on the Google Earth Engine Repo, but found a preexisting issue:

https://github.com/google/earthengine-api/issues/16

In the issue the developers acknowledge the problem, but indicate that they will not fix it due to limitations with the underlying `Tk` package.

Here is a quote from the issue:

> We have not been actively maintaining the mapclient object, because it
>   depends on Tk, a graphical user interface toolkit, which behaves
>   differently on different machines.
>   Could you describe your use case that requires mapclient? We may be
>   able to suggest an alternative approach.

The google developers offered to submit a workaround, but so far no workaround has been posted.

Hence, I was wondering if anyone else had found a suitable workaround in Python3.6 for this problem?

By way of a genuine code example, I can offer the code below from the Google examples repo:

```
import datetime
import ee
import ee.mapclient

ee.Initialize()
ee.mapclient.centerMap(-95.738, 18.453, 9)

# Filter the LE7 collection to a single date.
collection = (ee.ImageCollection('LE7_L1T')
              .filterDate(datetime.datetime(2002, 11, 8),
                          datetime.datetime(2002, 11, 9)))
image = collection.mosaic().select('B3', 'B2', 'B1')

# Display the image normally.
ee.mapclient.addToMap(image, {'gain': '1.6, 1.4, 1.1'}, 'Land')

# Add and stretch the water.  Once where the elevation is masked,
# and again where the elevation is zero.
elev = ee.Image('srtm90_v4')
mask1 = elev.mask().eq(0).And(image.mask())
mask2 = elev.eq(0).And(image.mask())
ee.mapclient.addToMap(
    image.mask(mask1), {'gain': 6.0, 'bias': -200}, 'Water: Masked')
ee.mapclient.addToMap(
    image.mask(mask2), {'gain': 6.0, 'bias': -200}, 'Water: Elev 0')
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if there is still an issue with import ee.mapclient in Python 3 but here is a work around using the [folium package](http://python-visualization.github.io/folium/) that can have similar methods to the ee.mapclient. However, this was will render the result in your web browser and not as a popup window (unless using a Jupyter notebook, then you can just call the folium map object to render).

```
import ee
import folium
import datetime
import webbrowser

ee.Initialize()

class eeMapHack(object):
    def __init__(self,center=[0, 0],zoom=3):
        self._map = folium.Map(location=center,zoom_start=zoom)
        return

    def addToMap(self,img,vizParams,name):
         map_id = ee.Image(img.visualize(**vizParams)).getMapId()
         tile_url_template = "https://earthengine.googleapis.com/map/{mapid}/{{z}}/{{x}}/{{y}}?token={token}"
         mapurl = tile_url_template.format(**map_id)
         folium.WmsTileLayer(mapurl,name=name).add_to(self._map)

         return

    def addLayerControl(self):
         self._map.add_child(folium.map.LayerControl())
         return


# initialize map object
eeMap = eeMapHack(center=[18.453,-95.738],zoom=9)

# Filter the LE7 collection to a single date.
collection = (ee.ImageCollection('LE7_L1T')
          .filterDate(datetime.datetime(2002, 11, 8),
                      datetime.datetime(2002, 11, 9)))
image = collection.mosaic().select('B3', 'B2', 'B1')
eeMap.addToMap(image, {'gain': '1.6, 1.4, 1.1'}, 'Land')

# Add and stretch the water.  Once where the elevation is masked,
# and again where the elevation is zero.
elev = ee.Image('srtm90_v4')
mask1 = elev.mask().eq(0).And(image.mask())
mask2 = elev.eq(0).And(image.mask())

eeMap.addToMap(image.mask(mask1), {'gain': 6.0, 'bias': -200}, 'Water: Masked')
eeMap.addToMap(image.mask(mask2), {'gain': 6.0, 'bias': -200}, 'Water: Elev 0')

# add layer control to map
eeMap.addLayerControl()

outHtml = 'map.html' # temporary file path, change if needed
eeMap._map.save(outHtml)

webbrowser.open('file://'+outHtml)
```

You should get an interactive web map in your browser with your analysis results that looks like this: 
[image]