# How to display a Protein Data Bank PDB in a Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, mdanalysis

I am trying to follow this [post](https://www.mdanalysis.org/2016/03/14/nglview/), but it fails to display a PDB inside a Jupyter notebook:

```
import MDAnalysis as mda
import nglview as nv
from nglview.datafiles import PDB, XTC

u = mda.Universe(PDB, XTC)

protein = u.select_atoms('protein')
```

When I try to do:

```
w = nv.show_mdanalysis(protein)
w
```

I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-499e28f0ffd3> in <module>()
----> 1 w = nv.show_mdanalysis(protein)
      2 w

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nglview-0.4-py3.5.egg/nglview/__init__.py in show_mdanalysis(atomgroup, **kwargs)
    118     '''
    119     structure_trajectory = MDAnalysisTrajectory(atomgroup)
--> 120     return NGLWidget(structure_trajectory, **kwargs)
    121 
    122 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nglview-0.4-py3.5.egg/nglview/__init__.py in __init__(self, structure, trajectory, representations, parameters, **kwargs)
    347         if parameters:
    348             self.parameters = parameters
--> 349         self.set_structure(structure)
    350         if trajectory:
    351             self.trajectory = trajectory

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nglview-0.4-py3.5.egg/nglview/__init__.py in set_structure(self, structure)
    372     def set_structure(self, structure):
    373         self.structure = {
--> 374             "data": structure.get_structure_string(),
    375             "ext": structure.ext,
    376             "params": structure.params

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nglview-0.4-py3.5.egg/nglview/__init__.py in get_structure_string(self)
    313                 "'MDAnalysisTrajectory' requires the 'MDAnalysis' package"
    314             )
--> 315         import cStringIO
    316         u = self.atomgroup.universe
    317         u.trajectory[0]

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cStringIO'
```

---

Edit Feb. 2020: I believe this is not an issue anymore if the libraries you are using updated their code to python3 properly: [python 3.x ImportError: No module named 'cStringIO'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28200366/python-3-x-importerror-no-module-named-cstringio), and it should be ok by now as python2 is deprecated.

Comment: nglview 0.4 seems terrible out of date, the latest on https://github.com/arose/nglview/releases is 1.1.4. (Your problem looks like code that was not properly configured to run under Python 2 *and* Python 3.)

Comment: @orbeckst I run under python 3.x. But that's what Fonda install

Comment: In a conda environment with Python 3.6 I did a `conda install nglview` and it pulled *1.1.3-py36_0 conda-forge* (I use conda-forge channel) with jupyter 4.4.0. The example from https://www.mdanalysis.org/2016/03/14/nglview/ worked as advertised.

Comment: *I run under python 3.x. But that's what Fonda install*. Maybe the default conda channel carries outdated nglview packages?

Comment: Aren't you using conda? At least that what it looks like from your stack trace. Can you try uninstalling nglview with `conda remove nglview`? If this fails then this package might have been pip or easy_installed. Try `pip remove nglview`. If this still not helping, `rm -r` everything related to nglview manually. Then `conda install -c conda-forge nglview`. (I tried conda installation under Ubuntu 16.04.4 and Python 3.6.4 and it worked without problems.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would attempt to get a clean nglview installation via [conda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/) (and the [Anaconda distribution](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/)):

Try uninstalling nglview with

```
conda remove nglview
```

just in case there's an old version. If this conda-remove fails then this package might have been `pip` or `easy_installed`. Try `pip remove nglview`. If this still not helping, you have to look for the installed nglview package and manually remove it with `rm` but I do not want to put copy&paste instructions here as this requires careful looking at files.

Once all traces of nglview have been removed, install the latest version of [nglview from the conda-forge channel](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/nglview) with `conda`:

```
conda install -c conda-forge nglview
```