# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cStringIO' ·

Tags: python, import, python-import

I am new to python, and I am running setoolkit, I have been notified cstringio module not found, I read a couple of solutions online like going to the python changelog and making some changes. My issue is I don't know how to access the changelog or where to, so I can import the solutions I saw online. Any help, please

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cStringIO' ·

Comment: did you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28200366/python-3-x-importerror-no-module-named-cstringio -- possible duplicate

Comment: Which python version are you using?

Answer (score 3):

I think you are using python 3.x
No module named 'cStringIO' with python 3.x
As i know cStringIO no longer exists in 3.x. May be you can use io.StringIO

your should use this

```
from io import StringIO
```

Read this link:
https://github.com/Infinidat/infi.clickhouse_orm/issues/27

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that it was replaced in Python 3 by from io import StringIO.  This works in both 2 and 3 version:

```
from io import BytesIO     # for handling byte strings
from io import StringIO    # for handling unicode strings
```