# can no longer import import pandas as pd

Tags: python, pandas

I used to be able to `import pandas as pd`, now it no longer works.
It started after I was trying to write code to send email.
In the stack trace it said It could not find module email, so I tried to `pip install email` but got the following error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cStringIO'
```

This is the stack trace i got for trying to import:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/tpottel/programming/java/eclipse projects/BBitBotCoinUsing2/bitcoinserver/python/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import email
  File "C:\Users\tpottel\programming\java\eclipse projects\BBitBotCoinUsing2\bitcoinserver\python\email.py", line 1, in <module>
    import smtplib
  File "C:\python64bit\lib\smtplib.py", line 47, in <module>
    import email.utils
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'email.utils'; 'email' is not a package
```

Comment: Might this be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28200366/python-3-x-importerror-no-module-named-cstringio

Comment: When I import pandas it says no package email when i try to pip install email i get the error No module named 'cStringIO'

Comment: How about `from io import StringIO`?