# Why can't I install email for Python

Tags: python, installation, pycharm

How can I fix this error:

```
>pip install email
Collecting email
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/71/e7/816030d3b0426c130040bd068be62b9213357ed02896f5d9badcf46d1b5f/email-4.0.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "H:\PycharmProjects\WinScripts\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
        import setuptools.version
      File "H:\PycharmProjects\WinScripts\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\version.py", line 1, in <module>
        import pkg_resources
      File "H:\PycharmProjects\WinScripts\venv\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
        import email.parser
      File "C:\Users\lawrence\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fu_huz8v\email\email\parser.py", line 10, in <module>
        from cStringIO import StringIO
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cStringIO'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\lawrence\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fu_huz8v\email\
```

EDIT 1:

If email is a standard package why does it fail:

```
H:\PycharmProjects\WinScripts\venv\Scripts\python.exe H:/PycharmProjects/WinScripts/email.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:/PycharmProjects/WinScripts/email.py", line 1, in <module>
    import smtplib
  File "C:\Users\lawrence\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\smtplib.py", line 47, in <module>
    import email.utils
  File "H:\PycharmProjects\WinScripts\email.py", line 2, in <module>
    from email.mime.text import MIMEText
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'email.mime'; 'email' is not a package

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Are you sure you want this library? looks like it's made for python 2 also there has been no updates made to this library since 2007.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28204760/4983469

Comment: ANSWER: My file was called email.py. I renamed it and it now works